# Role of Omega-3 in exercise induced bronchospasm?

Tags: nutrition, asthma

I have mild exercise induced bronchospasm (EIB, once called exercise induced asthma), to where I have been prescribed inhalers (ProAir HFA - Albuterol sulfate) but have very rarely needed to use them post endurance exercise sessions.

I ran across a [publication referring to a study](http://newsinfo.iu.edu/news-archive/24265.html) on a new Omega-3 formulation from an Australian mussel source, indicating that supplementation with this had a drastic (59%) reduction impact on EIB both during and after exercise bouts. (With a disclaimer that the formulator of the Omega-3 supplement paid for, but did not participate in the study).

The merits of the study aside, I'm interested in knowing what the mechanism of action would be in the Omega-3 formulation that could cause this reduction?

Answer (score 1):

Since all of the studies on this specific product seem not only mussel-like but downright fishy when reporting large effects the following is a bit speculative and just *assumes* that it actually works:

Two aspects of action seem possible:

EIB is often seen as  ["even cases of asthma in which exercise appears to be the only trigger of bronchial obstruction (pure EIA) may be manifestations of chronic inflammation of the airways."](http://www.jacionline.org/article/S0091-6749(07)00570-2/fulltext)

- The clam-extract is said to contain 30 PUFAs and especially the Omega-3 fatty acids EPA and DHA. When the ratio of Omega-3 is moved towards the optimum it is commonly believed to [reduce](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23456976) [inflammation](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3914936).
  [Omega-3 fatty acids and inflammatory processes: from molecules to man.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/28900017)
- The extract is said to be an inhibitor for the [5-lipoxygenase](http://www.atsjournals.org/doi/abs/10.1164/ajrccm.157.6.mar-1) pathway and might therefore be called an [antileukotriene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leukotriene).

The product differs from what was marketed as an anti-arthritis medication which [largely proved unsuccessful](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10067-005-0001-8). If the main action is indeed from the PUFAs then I wonder how much exactly is in those pills and why it should not be possible to use the PUFAs  and [other inflammation reducing foods](https://www.health.harvard.edu/staying-healthy/foods-that-fight-inflammation) [from](http://www.webmd.com/diet/anti-inflammatory-diet-road-to-good-health) other [sources](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4559234/). A more optimised [ratio of fatty acids](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12442909) is advised anyway.